# rss - getting a feed in php, what is the limit?

Tags: php, rss, limit, feed

I made this piece of php code which grabs a RSS feed, but I'm wondering:
**Is there a limit for the amount of items it can get from that feed?**

I want to know, because if it needs to load a lot of messages, my webpage will slow down...

You can see the feed here: -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit exists, but I think it depends on your php configuration.
Every php configuration define a **script time limit and** a **script memory limit**, so your script end when you reach one of those limits.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds smart indeed.
Another thing I could do is load the data via AJAX and show the user the data is loading.
But to get back to your example: how would I specify those properties in CURL in php?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is any limit. Also, I noticed that there are 38 items which is not big.

Comment: Yeah, It's just something I was wondering, not something im having problems with right now actually. Though I was wondering how that feed works: does it keep adding items, or would it keep the max of 38 items?

Answer (score 1):

- **it is a remote file**, getting it is always slow if you compare performances of a local file,
  even if the server is fast
- if the remote file is big, you can set a timeout using curl http://www.php.net/curl when downloading
- to speedup loading you can cache the file locally (and refresh every hour?)
- xml parsing can be extremely slow if is made in the user space code (some random lib, pear extension) use http://www.php.net/dom or http://www.php.net/xmlreader or http://www.php.net/simplexml or lib based on these core modules. I suggest to use DOM.

hope this helps

Comment: I am using simplexml [my teacher showed that to me to use {I havent actually seen the others}], what is the difference between DOM and simplexml?
Also, there is no need to cache, as the feed changes pretty fast, and I only need like 10 messages.
Doesnt simplexml have a limit function or something? [this would pprobably be too good to be true :P ]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're fetching the feed from another server, it could take some time for your script to fetch the feed. If the feed is large (few hundred records) your script may also need additional time and memory to process that. Having said that, you can cache the feed for, say 1 hour instead of loading and parsing it every time. The `ttl` field in the feed can give you and idea of for how long you should cache the feed.

Comment: There is no need to cache the data in my application, as the feed refreshes very fast [it shows traveling data [interruptions, changes, etc.] so i just need to read, for example 10 messages.
Would that be possible to specify, because its about an RSS feed, which has a certain amount of number?